# based on 4 values calculate price elasticity, QTY, and revenue

Tags: economics

I'm calculating price elasticity, QTY, and revenue. But I don't understand why price point 2 + 1,8 + 1,6 etc are negative values.
Can anyone explain the logic here?
I can forward the Excel file upon request.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjBjg.png)

QTY
-86.358.654.443.600.200.000.000
-86.358.654.443.600.200.000.000
-86.358.654.443.600.200.000.000
1.562.456.412.924.750.000.000.000
-13.353.255.812.646.700.000.000.000
71.629.731.799.382.200.000.000.000
-270.270.514.977.585.000.000.000.000
761.765.243.873.840.000.000.000.000
-1.662.253.556.922.770.000.000.000.000
2.871.577.274.342.580.000.000.000.000
-3.981.673.143.281.680.000.000.000.000
4.465.067.840.296.370.000.000.000.000
-4.059.927.343.261.740.000.000.000.000
2.986.867.970.705.740.000.000.000.000
-1.765.399.328.645.510.000.000.000.000
827.380.774.773.874.000.000.000.000
-300.968.281.915.882.000.000.000.000
82.117.073.933.395.800.000.000.000
-15.872.431.042.918.400.000.000.000
1.953.844.210.962.580.000.000.000
-118.603.147.016.950.000.000.000
578.310.517.566.495.000.000
26.236.668.613.717.600.000
2.382.983.842.389.350.000
314.917.353.258.725.000
53.499.744.800.765.300
10.939.261.673.645.300
2.584.884.413.091.240
686.719.854.185.475
201.116.229.122.102
63.979.064.267.779
21.857.356.900.984
7.946.865.581.041
3.052.456.630.820
1.231.223.238.734
518.880.593.526
227.504.047.013
103.399.651.713
48.561.519.326
23.502.929.790
11.694.164.596
5.969.228.072
3.120.019.371
1.667.106.690
909.262.048
505.536.076
286.171.975
164.754.648
96.371.998
57.223.141
34.461.869
21.033.946
13.002.073
8.134.545
5.147.814
3.293.373
2.128.943
1.389.904
916.030
609.198
408.660
278.620
249.530
220.440
108.140
53.910
27.292
14.020
7.304
3.857
2.063
1.117
612
339
190
108
62
36
21
12
7
4
3
2
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Can you copy the values of the QTY´s into the question? In general it is because the rel. change of the quantities is negative which is $\large{\frac{\Delta q}{q}=\frac{q_1-q_0}{q_0}}$ But I can´t say why the sign is flipping from row to row at the column QTY.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have included all QTY values now. For price, it goes from 0-10 jumping one decimal at a time (0,1 , 0,2, 0,3 etc)

Comment: As I said: "I can´t say why the sign is flipping from row to row at the column QTY"  In reality negative quantities doesn´t make sense. I can only say how the %-changes have been calculated.

Comment: it seems like when column G hits -100% the problem starts.